# Completely lost in trying to mutate property in sequence

Tags: f#, seq, imperative

I am completely at loss why this code doesn't mutate a member variable in a sequence of types:

```
for p in prescrs do
    p.ATC <- "A"
    for c in p.Drug.Components do
        for s in c.Substances do
                s.DoseTotal.Adjust <- adjustKg
                s.DoseTotal.Time <- "DAY"
                s.DoseTotal.Unit <- s.DrugConcentration.Unit
                s.DoseRate.Adjust <- adjustKg
                s.DoseRate.Time <- "DAY"
                s.DoseRate.Unit <- s.DrugConcentration.Unit
```

prescrs is a sequence of Prescriptions which is a very simple 'POCO' defined as a type with member values. I don't have clue why this doesn't work.

I tried a simple test case like:

```
type IterTest () =
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val IterTests = [] |> List.toSeq : IterTest seq with get, set

let iterseq = 
    [
        new IterTest(Name = "Test1")
        new IterTest(Name = "Test2")
    ] 
    |> List.toSeq

iterseq |> Seq.iter(fun x -> x.IterTests <- iterseq)
iterseq |> Seq.iter(fun x -> 
    x.IterTests
    |> Seq.iter(fun x' -> x'.Name <- "itered"))
```

But here the result is as expected. So, can't even quite reproduce my problem???

Found a solution (without really understanding the problem above). When I first convert the prescrs sequence to a list like:

```
let prescrs = prescrs |> Seq.toList
```

and then do the imperative looping, properties do get mutated.

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" mean? How is `prescrs` produced? (BTW `let prescrs = prescrs |> Seq.toList` is a conversion, not a cast.)

Comment: @ildjarn With 'doesn't work' I mean, the properties are not changed. In the second example the properties do change. Both examples are an iteration over a sequence, so I expected the same behavior.

Comment: But how do you know the value haven't changed? Maybe your test is flawed... _And how is `prescrs` produced?_ How do you expect to get help when you don't show enough code for relevant context?

Comment: @ildjarn See the answer below, I am happy now, thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this sample:

```
type Mutable() = 
    member val Iterated = false with get, set

let muts = Seq.init 5 (fun _ -> printfn "init"; Mutable())

let muts2 = muts // try again with let muts2 = muts |> List.ofSeq

printfn "Before iter"

for a in muts2 do
    printfn "iter"    
    a.Iterated <- true 

printfn "After iter" 

muts2 |> List.ofSeq
```

and check how `iter` and `init` are interleaved.

`Seqs` are lazy, but are not cached once computed. So even if you imperatively try to mutate some of the elements in your `prescrs` sequence, it all goes away once you pull `prescrs` again. If you change `prescrs` into a concrete collection type like list before doing the mutation, you no longer hit the same problem. Note that things might get even trickier if what you have is a seq inside a seq inside a seq.

The best idea would be to avoid mutation in the first place though.

Comment: Thanks, very well explained, got it.